# How to edit already filled radio buttons from data base

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

How do I edit already filled buttons from the database and have the newly selected option selected once I submit the form?  I tried this code below but it only works when I refresh the page.

```
<label for="shopping">Shopping?</label></br>
    <span class="yes">Yes</span><input class="check" type="radio" name="shopping" 
    <?php if ($newShopping == "1" || $shopping == "1") {echo "checked";} ?> value="1" />
    <span class="no">No</span><input class="check" type="radio" name="shopping" 
    <?php if ($newShopping == "0" || $shopping == "0") echo "checked"; ?> value="0" />
```

Comment: You'd have to post the data BACK to the server-side. Either via a `<form>` submission or AJAX.

Comment: You'd also want your `name` values to be different for each of your `<input>` fields, though based on the fact that they're mutually exclusive, it sounds like you only need one `<input>` to begin with...